# The favicon is missing for the maintenance page in the Firefox browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, favicon, maintenance

A few minutes before I see the maintenance page in MSE (*"We are currently offline for maintenance"*), when seeing the page in Firefox, the favicon is missing, whereas the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) was displayed in Chrome.

**Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

[image: Google Chrome]

**Mozilla Firefox Version 66.0.3 (64-bit)**

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I have reported this to our dev team. We will circle back once its been looked at.

Comment: @SpencerG Thank you. The favicon is not displaying for https://www.stackstatus.net/ in the Firefox browser too.

Comment: How does time enter the picture ("A few minutes before")? What role does time play? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum They probably meant "A few minutes earlier I saw the..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems the bug had been fixed sometime before.

Now, the MSE offline page has the favicon in the Firefox browser.

Browser version: Mozilla Firefox 112.0 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: Might have been Firefox issue, fixed in some update.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard I hope No. The same issue exists for https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/ page. It has the favicon in Chrome but not in Firefox. Or in a other way, Chrome set default favicon (The globe) if there is no custom favicon, but Firefox doesn't handle it.